# Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ ) in java when define String

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I try to define `\b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\` inside the string but getting 
**`Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`**.

I am getting encypted data from web, like this.

`String testString="4sXuWJ4juj\/RS46l7xFLK|awhVBqNga\/BbyNt7t3Q\/DJ7OhHNix8G2PDyAFSGw+1E=`";

Here i want to split string based on **`|`**. so that i wann try to put in string. any idea how to split based on | in java.

Any idea, how to possible to split, if i am getting such type of string data **testString** from web.using certain spitting parameter. like |, \ and others.

Comment: `\/` is indeed an invalid escape sequence - what are you asking?

Comment: is that possible to put above encypted data in to stirng. i want to split base |.

Comment: You need to escape the `"\/"` using two `"\\/"`

Comment: Try This 
 
String testString="4sXuWJ4juj\\/RS46l7xFLK|awhVBqNga\\/BbyNt7t3Q\\/DJ7OhHNix8G2PDyAFSGw+1E=";
  System.out.println(testString);
You need to give an additional "\" after every "\" and finally make it "\\".

Comment: @SaqibRezwan, i don't know how much \ in string. this comes from web if i hit server.

Comment: Can you replace every "\" with "\\" like the java function replaceAll. Sorry, If you could give a little bit more specific scenario that I could understand properly.

Comment: but i replace every "\" with "\\" , then it effect when decrypt this string. i cannot put that.

Comment: Can't you use byte array? its better in that way.

Comment: if you still want to use String, the additional "\" should not be affect the String. Java automatically removes one "\" while it tries to parse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define a regex as a string literal in Java, two different escapings are going on:

- First, Java compiler interprets escape sequences in the string. It supports eight escape sequences in string literals
- Second, the Regex engine interprets the string after Java escape sequences have been interpreted by the compiler. Regex supports escape sequences of its own, letting you escape its metacharacters. In particular, it supports `\|`.

However, in order for Regex engine to "see" `\|`, you need to escape the slash for the Java compiler, i.e. write `\\|`.

To avoid confusion in situations like that, I prefer making a character class from metacharacters, e.g. `[|]`, `[*]`, `[+]`, and so on. In this way you do not have to double-escape many common metacharacters. Of course, this trick is not universal - for example, it does not work with `]`.